# If I want to connect EC2 to RDS in a VPC, what hostname should I use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, vpc

I have an application running in EC2 and a PostgreSQL db running in RDS, both inside the same VPC. I believe I have created the necessary security group, but how do I determine the hostname of the db server to use from my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the row for that instance in the RDS dashboard. Then you can see the DNS name to use next to "Endpoint:".

[image: RDS]

My RDS instance in the image above has the domain: `[redacted].us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com`. Hovering over the information icon (`i` on a dark circle) next to it shows me the security groups that can access it.